# MFC UI Automation graceful shutdown

Tags: mfc, ui-automation

Our MFC app hangs during shutdown if any UI Automation client is active (Such as Inspect. Windows Eyes, UI Spy etc.)
The reason is BOOL AFXAPI AfxOleCanExitApp() returns false if any Ole Objects exist. The app then goes into hidden server mode.

I have seen similar posts dealing with Document objects. The general solution is to set the object count to 0, close normally then set the count back in the OnClose of the main frame.
This is a poor solution for UI Automation. It causes memory leaks and invalid objects in the Client app ( Inspect actually crashes after a time).

Has anyone seen a proper way to tell UI clients this server is going away and release all objects?

Comment: Just confirming that I've also experienced this behaviour randomly.

Comment: I found the Microsoft official answer to this problem here...

[link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732027/cwnd-createaccessibleproxy-can-cause-mfc-applications-to-hang-upon-exit-and-corrupt-their-internal-module-state-object-counts)

Their solution was to eliminate the lock mechanism. I don't see how this solves the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real good way to shut down graceful. There is no graceful way to stop any server when it is still in use. You can only do necessary cleanup.

1. You have Connections to you objects. What is graceful if you cut them? You can use CoDisconnectObject for every object. But there is no difference when you terminate the application. Also using this function doesn't reduce the objects lock count! But you can delete the object without getting a crash with an access from the other COM clients.
2. The draw back: CoDisconnectObject only works for external links. If you have internal COM pointers the object, they are not affected. So those may still use your object...
3. When you really find every object that has an external connection you can destroy it. And if you have no internal COM-pointers you can delete your objects even with a usage count !=0. But in lots of cases I have other dependent COM-objects that are linked...

The only real good way to terminate gracefully is to stop all applications that use your application as a server first! And exit after this is done... ;)

So if you want to force a shutdown. Disconnect what you can. Free as many resources you know. Than ignore the applications lock count and exit. Memory is freed, even if the debug version will report a leak. Problematic are only other resources (files, mutexes, system objects...) that may need a better handling as closing the application...

Comment: Thanks xMRi. I was afraid that was the case. The objects are buried in the MFC UI Automation infrastructure. I found where they are created but the comptr is not added to any list.
The IAccessible interface defines events like EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY but I can find no instance of its use in the MFC source.
UI Automation is not your normal COM scenario. Usually you have a server and multiple clients use it. Here we have one client using every app running that must come and go throughout the use of the computer. Microsoft must have taken that into consideration right?